# What is the command to open a webpage in a new chromium tab?

Tags: chromium, command-line

I know that if I use `chromium-browser --app=http://...` it will open a new Application Shortcut window without the tab bar or navigation bar. I want to know the command that will open a webpage in a regular Chromium window, or if one is already open, open it in a new tab.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:
`chromium-browser www.google.de`

Comment: Wow, it was that simple? Well, thank you very much, now my chrome quicklists can be extra efficient!

Comment: You can also force multiple windows/sessions by adding `--data-dir=/tmp/identifier`, for example.

Comment: Is it possible to avoid it exiting when the browser is opened? I am running an interactive gradation script where I want to open the browser at a certain step, and wait for it to closed. Running "firefox" CLI does not exit before the browser is closed, I am going to use that for now.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe add:

```
DISPLAY=:0
```

Before

```
chromium-browser www.google.de
```

Like this:

```
DISPLAY=:0 chromium-browser www.google.de
```